# How to update Python 3.5.2 shell (IDLE) to the latest version 3.7.3?

Tags: 16.04, python

I have already installed Python 3.7.3 version via command line and cross-checked it by typing

```
python3 -V
```

command but still, my Python IDLE is set to 3.5.2 version. I need to know how to update it even though Python 3.7.3 latest version is already installed on my system. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please take the time for the [tour], and read [ask], to learn how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to your Python installations being seperately accessible by `python3.5` and `python3.7` (while `python3` and `python` are only symlinks that point to one of those), you should have `idle3.5` and `idle3.7` available in your path, with `idle` pointing to the first.

If this doesn't solve your problem, please be more specific on what you tried, how you installed Python, and what you expect.